# Prolog: Doubling the value of each element in a list of lists and returning a single list

Tags: prolog

I need write a set of clauses that take a list of integer lists and return a single list with all the elements doubled.

For example:

```
?- double([[1,2],[3]], X).
Yes
X = [2,4,6]
```

I have a set of clauses called mega_append that return a single list from a list of lists.

For example:

```
?- mega_append([[1,2],[3]], X).
Yes
X = [1,2,3]
```

Here is my progress (m_a is short for mega_append):

```
double([],[]).
double(List,[H1|T1]) :-
    m_a(List,[H2|T2]),
    H1 is 2 * H2,
    double(T2, T1).
```

I'll try to explain how I thought it would work.  I flatten the first list and split it up into a head and a tail (H2 and T2).  I split the second list into a head and a tail (H1 and T1).  I check to make sure that H1 (the doubled value) is equal to 2 times H2 (the original value).  If it is then I check the rest of the list.  Eventually if they all match correctly I should be left with two empty lists which should match the first clause and return yes.

It works when there is only a single value (for example: `double([[1]], X)`).  Can anyone offer any insight into what I am doing wrong?  Is my logic or code incorrect?

Comment: What happens if mega_append get a single list instead of a list of lists? Ex. ?- mega_append([2,3], X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that T2 is a single list so List after the recursive call is not a list of lists.

To solve this you can first use mega_append to flatten the list and then use an auxiliary predicate to work on the flattened list.
I.e. the double will look like this:

```
double([],[]).
double(List,X) :-
    m_a(List,FList),
    double_aux(List, FList).
```

**Edit:**
Here is a way to only use one clause since you want to see one.
I recommend using an auxiliary predicate.

```
double([],[]).
double([[]],[]).
double(List,[H1|T1]) :-
    mega_append(List,[H2|T2]),
    H1 is 2 * H2,
    double([T2], T1).
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to figure it out using that method.  I'm still convinced there exists a way to do it using only one set of clauses though.

Comment: There is often a `flatten/2` procedure which does what your `m_a/2` does.

Comment: There does indeed. I have edited my post with an example, but imo using an auxiliary predicate is better than that example. (There might be some nice way which I don't see atm.)

Comment: @rvirding: It does not work the same. If you replace m_a with flatten in the original code you'll say that it works. I.e. flatten(L1,L2), L1 = L2 when L1 is flat.

Comment: OK, `flatten` does allow a wider range of input than `mega_append`. You could just call it `append/2` and let the different number of arguments differentiate between appending 2 lists or a list of lists.

Comment: It is good that you mention `flatten/2` as it is definitely something worth knowing about. At the same time this is homework and I have a suspicion that `mega_append` was crafted as a less powerful version of `flatten` to particularly prevent the first attempt by OP. Even with `flatten` I would create a predicate which solves the problem for a flattened list and then solve it for the more general case using that version. You know, problem decomposition. Originally I also tried to fit everything in a single predicate, but sometimes it's better to break the problem up.

Answer (score 2):

Using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), we define the [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)  [nonterminal](http://www.metalevel.at/dcg.html) `double//1` like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

double([])     --> [].
double([D|Ds]) --> {DD #= D*2}, [DD], double(Ds).
```

Let's run some queries—using [`phrase/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dphrase.html), 
[`apply:foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4), and nonterminal `double//1`:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

?- phrase(foldl(double,[[1,2],[3]]),Xs).
Xs = [2,4,6].

?- phrase(foldl(double,[[A,B],[C]]),[2,4,6]).
A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
```

Want more examples using `phrase/[2,3]`?
Read [this](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dgru_002dexa.html) SICStus Prolog [manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/index.html) page!